# Как передать большой вывод одной исполняемой программы в python программу

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я работаю на Linux. Я адаптирую под свои нужды одну программу на python. В неё вторым аргументом должен вбиватся файл с выводом другой программы. Но в моей ситуации и в дальнейших вывод будет настолько огромен что неуместится на мой жёсткий диск. Поэтому я хочу передавать вывод первой исполняемой программы напрямую в мою python программу. Хотел спросить как это можно реализовать

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону fifo-файлов ([man mkfifo](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo)). Вы можете передать такой файл как аргумент и читать из него в то время, как другая программа (вывод которой вам нужен) в него пишет. Конечно, в вызывающем скрипте потребуется некоторая синхронизация действий

Comment: @avp Спасибо большое! Хотел ещё спросить как вы смотрите на решение задачи в виде subprocess и передачи вывода через PIPE

Comment: Безусловно, так можно. Вообще, в духе \*nix делать программы, состоящие из независимых частей (фильтров), которые можно объединять конвейером (пайпами) для передачи данных. Посмотрите, так сделаны большинство утилит и клеем для них служит shell. Поэтому, если вы переделаете свою python-программу в таком духе, то imho это будет правильно

Comment: @avp большое спасибо. Сказать честно, как только я от вас узнал про именованные каналы (fifo) я нашёл решения на проэкты которые давно хотел сделать но не знал как реализовать. Ещё раз низкий поклон вам! )

Comment: Спасибо, конечно. Приятно слышать. А вам бы я посоветовал посмотреть  *`/usr/include/*.h`* и почитать manpages на функции и системные вызовы, которые вам в этих *`.h`* приглянутся. Т.о. станет понятно, что вообще система умеет делать